# Tags not firing and events not registering in single page web application built in Angular 4

Tags: angular, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I'm currently working with an Angular 4 application. The code for index.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Copofi</title>
    <base href="/">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
            'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
            event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j = d.createElement(s),
            dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src =
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-H1TH3R3');
    </script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-H1TH3R3" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

    <app-root></app-root>

    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-12345678-9', 'auto');  
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I turn on preview, no events are triggered, detected or recorded whatsoever. I have no idea where to start, and what I'm missing! The only events fired are Page Viewed, DOM Ready and Window Loaded. It won't even detect clicks on the page.

Working theories:

1) Is it not working because this is a single page application where content is loaded into ?

2) Is there a conflicting JS library? The console doesn't give me any errors though.

Side note: I've replaced my tracking codes with fake ones.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using GTM (Google Tag Manager) and GA on the same page.
In my opinion You need to push the changes in datalayer and configure events based on data layer changes